# $.ajax response has values in console.log but not in specific values like: response.Liter

Tags: php, jquery, json

In a Bootsrap page I'm using jQuery to send different formulars zu a .php. With the jQuery I'm trying to took the result from the .php to show it to the user. But when I got the result from the php, something happend that i cant understand:
The incoming response give's in the console following result:
command:

`console.log("Test: "+response+"\n\n Test2: "+response.Richtwert1);`

result:

> Test: {"success": true, "Rechnung1": true, "Liter1": "2000",
>   "Entfernung1": "91.86", "Richtwert1": "2000", "PpLnetto1": "3.4",
>   "PpLbrutto1": "4.04", "Gesamtpreis1": "91.86", "Rechnung2": false,
>   "Rechnung3": false
>
> Test2: undefined

Hope someone here can help me to get my values out of this response.
Following the important parts of my program:
part of jQ in index.html:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('#Rechnen_button').on('click',function(){
            //Formular absenden
            //Alte ErrorMeldungen entfernen
            $( '#KundennameZeile' ).removeClass( 'has-error' );
            $( '#LiterZeile1' ).removeClass( 'has-error' );
            var formControl = true;

            //Variable einsammeln
            var Name = "Rechner";
            var Kundenname = $( '#Kundenname' ).val();
            var LiterAuswahlFeld1 = $( '#LiterAuswahlFeld1' ).text();
            var Liter1 = $( '#Liter1' ).val();
            var AB1 = $( '#AbladestellenAuswahlFeld1' ).text();
            var Raten1 = $( '#RatenAuswahlFeld1' ).text();
            var Ort = $( '#OrtAuswahlFeld' ).text();
            var Oel1 = $( '#OelsorteAuswahlFeld1' ).text();
            var LiterAuswahlFeld2 = $( '#LiterAuswahlFeld2' ).text();
            var Liter2 = $( '#Liter2' ).val();
            var AB2 = $( '#AbladestellenAuswahlFeld2' ).text();
            var Raten2 = $( '#RatenAuswahlFeld2' ).text();
            var Oel2 = $( '#OelsorteAuswahlFeld2' ).text();
            var LiterAuswahlFeld3 = $( '#LiterAuswahlFeld3' ).text();
            var Liter3 = $( '#Liter3' ).val();
            var AB3 = $( '#AbladestellenAuswahlFeld3' ).text();
            var Raten3 = $( '#RatenAuswahlFeld3' ).text();
            var Oel3 = $( '#OelsorteAuswahlFeld3' ).text();

            //Kontrolle ob alles wichtige für Rechnung 1 da ist
            if(Kundenname == '') {
                formControl = false;
                $( '#KundennameZeile' ).addClass( 'has-error' );
            }

            if(Liter1 == '') {
                formControl = false;
                $( '#LiterZeile1' ).addClass( 'has-error' );
            }

            if($.isNumeric(Liter1) == false) {
                formControl = false;
                $( '#LiterZeile1' ).addClass( 'has-error' );
            }

            if(formControl) {
                //Rechnung abschicken
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "post.php",
                    data: {
                        name:Name,
                        Kundenname:Kundenname,
                        LiterAuswahlFeld1:LiterAuswahlFeld1,
                        Liter1:Liter1,
                        AB1:AB1,
                        Raten1:Raten1,
                        Ort:Ort,
                        Oel1:Oel1,
                        LiterAuswahlFeld2:LiterAuswahlFeld2,
                        Liter2:Liter2,
                        AB2:AB2,
                        Raten2:Raten2,
                        Oel2:Oel2,
                        LiterAuswahlFeld3:LiterAuswahlFeld3,
                        Liter3:Liter3,
                        AB3:AB3,
                        Raten3:Raten3,
                        Oel3:Oel3
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log("Test: "+response+"\n\n Test2: "+response.Richtwert1);
                        if(!response.success) {
                            return response.msg;
                        } else {                    
                        $('#RichtwertErgebnis1').html(response.Richtwert1+' L.');
                            $('#EntfernungErgebnis1').html(response.Entfernung1+' €');
                            $('#PlLnettoErgebnis1').html(response.PpLnetto1+' Ct');
                            $('#PpLbruttoErgebnis1').html(response.PpLbrutto1+' Ct');
                            if(LiterAuswahlFeld1=="Liter") {
                                $('#GesamtbruttoErgebnis1').html(response.Gesamtpreis1+' €');
                            } else {
                                $('#GesamtbruttoErgebnis1').html(response.Gesamtpreis1+' € ergeben '+response.Liter1+' L.');
                                $('rechnungsergebnis_1 span:last-child').html('Gesamt brutto ergibt Liter');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

The post.php:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];

if (strlen($name) > 0) {
    if($name=='Rechner'){
        //Rechnung durchführen
        $Kundenname = $_POST['Kundenname'];
        $LiterAuswahlFeld1 = $_POST['LiterAuswahlFeld1'];
        $Liter1 = $_POST['Liter1'];
        $AB1 = $_POST['AB1'];
        $Raten1 = $_POST['Raten1'];
        $Ort = $_POST['Ort'];
        $Oel1 = $_POST['Oel1'];
        $LiterAuswahlFeld2 = $_POST['LiterAuswahlFeld2'];
        $Liter2 = $_POST['Liter2'];
        $AB2 = $_POST['AB2'];
        $Raten2 = $_POST['Raten2'];
        $Oel2 = $_POST['Oel2'];
        $LiterAuswahlFeld3 = $_POST['LiterAuswahlFeld3'];
        $Liter3 = $_POST['Liter3'];
        $AB3 = $_POST['AB3'];
        $Raten3 = $_POST['Raten3'];
        $Oel3 = $_POST['Oel3'];

//Something for you unimporant is deleted

        if(strlen($name) > 0 && ((strlen($Liter1) > 0 && is_numeric($Liter1))||(strlen($Liter2) > 0 && is_numeric($Liter2))||(strlen($Liter3) > 0 && is_numeric($Liter3)))) {
            if(strlen($Liter1) > 0 && is_numeric($Liter1)) {
                //Rechnung 1
                //Variablen Kontrolle
                if($LiterAuswahlFeld1!=='Max. Betrag') {$LiterAuswahlFeld1="Liter";}
                switch ($AB1) {
                    case 1;
                    case 2;
                    case 3;
                    case 4;
                    case 5;
                    case 6;
                    case 7;
                    case 8;
                    break;
                    default: 
                        $AB1=1;
                        break;
                }
                switch ($Raten1) {
                    case 1:
                        $Raten1=0;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $Raten1=1;
                        break;
                    case 3;
                        $Raten1=2;
                        break;
                    default: 
                        $Raten1=0;
                        break;
                }
                if($Oel1!=='Premium Heizöl') {$Oel1="Heizöl EL";}

                //Werte berechnen
                $rechnung1=preisrechner($Liter1, $LiterAuswahlFeld1, $AB1, $Raten1, $ortwert, $Oel1, $vkp);

                //Ausgabe für Rechnung
                $ergebnissRechnung1 = '"Rechnung1": true, "Liter1": "'.$rechnung1['Liter'].'", "Entfernung1": "'.$rechnung1['Entfernung'].'", "Richtwert1": "'.$rechnung1['Richtwert'].'", "PpLnetto1": "'.$rechnung1['PpLnetto'].'", "PpLbrutto1": "'.$rechnung1['PpLbrutto'].'", "Gesamtpreis1": "'.$rechnung1['Gesamtpreis'].'"';
            } else {
                $ergebnissRechnung1 = '"Rechnung1": false';
            }


            //Rechnung 2
            if(strlen($Liter2) > 0 && is_numeric($Liter2)) {
                //Variablen Kontrolle
                if($LiterAuswahlFeld2!=='Max. Betrag') {$LiterAuswahlFeld2="Liter";}
                switch ($AB2) {
                    case 1;
                    case 2;
                    case 3;
                    case 4;
                    case 5;
                    case 6;
                    case 7;
                    case 8;
                    break;
                    default: 
                        $AB2=1;
                        break;
                }
                switch ($Raten2) {
                    case 1:
                        $Raten2=0;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $Raten2=1;
                        break;
                    case 3;
                        $Raten2=2;
                        break;
                    default: 
                        $Raten2=0;
                        break;
                }
                if($Oel2!=='Premium Heizöl') {$Oel2="Heizöl EL";}

                //Werte berechnen
                $rechnung2=preisrechner($Liter2, $LiterAuswahlFeld2, $AB2, $Raten2, $ortwert, $Oel2, $vkp);

                //Ausgabe für Rechnung
                $ergebnissRechnung2 = '"Rechnung2": true, "Liter2": "'.$rechnung2['Liter'].'", "Entfernung2": "'.$rechnung2['Entfernung'].'", "Richtwert2": "'.$rechnung2['Richtwert'].'", "PpLnetto2": "'.$rechnung2['PpLnetto'].'", "PpLbrutto2": "'.$rechnung2['PpLbrutto'].'", "Gesamtpreis2": "'.$rechnung2['Gesamtpreis'].'"';
            } else {
                $ergebnissRechnung2 = '"Rechnung2": false';
            }

            //Rechnung 3
            if(strlen($Liter3) > 0 && is_numeric($Liter3)) {
                //Variablen Kontrolle
                if($LiterAuswahlFeld3!=='Max. Betrag') {$LiterAuswahlFeld3="Liter";}
                switch ($AB3) {
                    case 1;
                    case 2;
                    case 3;
                    case 4;
                    case 5;
                    case 6;
                    case 7;
                    case 8;
                    break;
                    default: 
                        $AB3=1;
                        break;
                }
                switch ($Raten3) {
                    case 1:
                        $Raten3=0;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $Raten3=1;
                        break;
                    case 3;
                        $Raten3=2;
                        break;
                    default: 
                        $Raten3=0;
                        break;
                }
                if($Oel3!=='Premium Heizöl') {$Oel3="Heizöl EL";}

                //Werte berechnen
                $rechnung3=preisrechner($Liter3, $LiterAuswahlFeld3, $AB3, $Raten3, $ortwert, $Oel3, $vkp);

                //Ausgabe für Rechnung
                $ergebnissRechnung3 = '"Rechnung3": true, "Liter3": "'.$rechnung3['Liter'].'", "Entfernung3": "'.$rechnung3['Entfernung'].'", "Richtwert3": "'.$rechnung3['Richtwert'].'", "PpLnetto3": "'.$rechnung3['PpLnetto'].'", "PpLbrutto3": "'.$rechnung3['PpLbrutto'].'", "Gesamtpreis3": "'.$rechnung3['Gesamtpreis'].'"';
            } else {
                $ergebnissRechnung3 = '"Rechnung3": false';
            }

            //Rückgabe
            $ergebniss= '{"success": true, '.$ergebnissRechnung1.', '.$ergebnissRechnung2.', '.$ergebnissRechnung3.'}';
            echo $ergebniss;

        } else {
            header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
            echo "Der Name und die Literanzahl von wenigstens einer Rechnung muss ausgefüllt sein.";
        }

    } else {
        header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
        echo "Etwas ist seltsam!";
    }
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request-1', true, 400);
    echo "Das Feld darf nicht leer sein!";
}
?>
```

Thanks for all helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have json - a string - and not a javascript object.

You need to parse it manually or tell jQuery that you expect json back so that jQuery can parse it automatically for you:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    // tell jQuery you expect json back
    dataType: "json",
    url: "post.php",
    // etc.
```

Apart from that, you should not create json manually in your php script. Instead, build an array with the required data structure and use `json_encode($your_data_structure)` at the end to encode it correctly.

Comment: Great answer, couldn't of explained it better myself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I add `dataType: "json",` to the $.ajax and create an array which I filled with commands like this `$ergebniss['PpLnetto3'] = $rechnung3['PpLnetto'];` and in the end i send the array with `echo json_encode($ergebniss);` Now i have no result in the console, no error alert and no response. Did i a follow-up error?

Comment: @Faror You should check the response in the developers tools, if you don't get anything, it is likely that the returned result is not valid json and you are going to the error handler in javascript. Are you echoing anything else perhaps?